# How to build a Fama & French model based on the international data provided by French?

Tags: asset-pricing, fama-french

I am trying to obtain a 3 factor Fama French model based on the "International Research Returns Data" provided on French home page

https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html

and I am having really a hard time.

The questions and answers I saw so far could not help me.

So the first part is how to obtain the HML and SMB out of the data provided, and second which values to use for the regression.

Thanks

Comment: This resource should help: https://medium.com/@joshuaisland/diy-fama-french-3-factor-model-bfd8c26525b Scroll down and you should see it says CRSP is the data source. Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this describes how to obtain the SMB and HML for a much extensive data set they provide. For the set in the example I would be able to do it myself. I need to look at the country specific level ("International Research Returns").